# capturing enter key in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I'm using [**select2**](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) to present an editable selectbox. When user writes a statement which does not appear in the `list(select2, data)`, I show a button to add this statement to the list.

Forcing users to click the button seems to me a little bit frustration. Is it possible to capture enter key in select2? I want to make user able to add his/her new statements into the list just by pressing enter key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('select2-search-field > input.select2-input').on('keyup', function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode === 13) 
      addToList($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: For me the selector that worked was was '.select2-search > input.select2-input', on select 3.4.5

Comment: Keyup event binding to select2 search input is not working on IE11.

Comment: Minor caveat, if you have multiple select2's on the same page, all of them will now attempt to `addToList($(this).val());` if you press Enter from their search fields as well.  I think select2 4.0 might resolve this (hand in hand with a better selector) but I'm stuck with 3.5 still trying to work out Bootstrap changes.

Comment: "all of them", yes, since the selector is only class-based.
If you want to enable this behaviour only on one select2 instance, just call $('#my-select2-instance').on...

Answer (score 7):

I'm using `Select2 4.0.3` and this works form me:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.select2-search__field', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        alert('Pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using Select2 4.0. This works for me;

```
$('.select2-search__field').on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13)
        {
            alert('Enter key');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm using 4.0.3, keyup doesn't work anymore. Using "input" works

Comment: I confirm, use "input" instead of "keyup".
In my case I want to run the trigger after changing the value of $('.select2-search__field')
and I settled with this code:
`$('.select2-search__field').val('new_value').trigger('input');`

Answer (score 2):

None of these worked in `Select2 4.0.6-rc1`, but this did:

```
$('#mySelect2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

It's detailed in the manual [here](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#event-data).

Answer (score 1):

This code can help you with class-based selections:

```
$('.select2-selection').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var YOUR_SELECT2_CUSTOM_CLASS = $(this).attr('aria-labelledby').includes('YOUR_SELECT2_CUSTOM_CLASS')
    if (YOUR_SELECT2_CUSTOM_CLASS && e.keyCode === 13) {
        alert($(".YOUR_SELECT2_CUSTOM_CLASS").val())
    }
});
```

Or you can use this:

```
$("YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS").bind("change keypress", function() {
  if (window.event.keyCode === 13) {
    alert("Enter Captured")
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If legacy select2 is used (some 3.5.4), then this option can be used:

```
$('#mySelect2').on('select2-selected', function (e) {
    console.log(e.params);
    // keypress enter script
});
```

It helped me a lot.
If you have two select2s on the page, then this is a great option!